# Match strings inside brackets when searching in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm using the `\((?!\s)([^()]+)(?<!\s)\)` regular expression to match `(string)` but not `( string )` nor `()` when searching in Sublime Text.

As VS Code doesn't support backreferences in regular expressions, I was wondering how can modify the original regex to get the same result in this editor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```
\(([^()\s](?:[^()]*[^()\s])?)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTLmXa/1)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()\s](?:[^()]*[^()\s])?)` - Group 1:

  - `[^()\s]` - a char other than `(`, `)` and a whitespace
  - `(?:[^()]*[^()\s])?` - an optional sequence (so as to also match strings like `(a)`, with 1 char inside parentheses) of

    - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
    - `[^()\s]` - a char other than `(`, `)` and a whitespace
- `\)` - a `)` char.